# Can't seem to find and toggle already expanded classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, packery

I have found the following code in combination with Packery to expand and shrink blocks when being clicked on. I want to add to the code that when clicking a block, all other blocks that currently are expanded shrink to their original size, so that only 1 block is expanded at the time.

This is the code

```
$( function() {
  var $container = $('.packery').packery();

  $container.on( 'click', '.item', function( event ) {
    var $item = $( event.currentTarget );
    var isExpanded = $item.hasClass('is-expanded');
    $item.toggleClass('is-expanded');
    if ( isExpanded ) {
      // if shrinking, just layout
      $container.packery();
    } else {
      // if expanding, fit it
      $container.packery( 'fit', event.currentTarget );
    }
  });
});
```

this is the codepen I found
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myLbmP

I've been trying using the .not selector, but I can't seem to rewrite it to work properly. Thanks in advance

Comment: this behavior is commonly referred as accordion, see [link](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
$( function() {
  var $container = $('.packery').packery();

  $container.on( 'click', '.item', function( event ) {
    var $item = $( event.currentTarget );
    var isExpanded = $item.hasClass('is-expanded');
    //NEW LINE BELOW
    $(".is-expanded").removeClass("is-expanded");
    if ( isExpanded ) {
      // if shrinking, just layout
      $container.packery();
    } else {
       $item.addClass('is-expanded');
      // if expanding, fit it
      $container.packery( 'fit', event.currentTarget );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh I see, works like a charm! I've been adding this line everywhere in the if and the else statement except for where you put it. Thanks